# Find if user is near a certain location iOS

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to make a app which will find nearby coffee shops and push notify users if found any within 1 mile. 
I just wanted to make sure How it can be done
This is what I have thought about till now

1. Get users Location
2. Update every minute in background and find if changed
3. If changed, find nearby Stores from the database on server
4. If found any nearby Stores, Push Notify user on their phone.
5. 1 notification per store, so if same store found in same location, it won't send push notification again.

Please do tell me, if this can be done. I'm just not sure about background location updating in background or even if the app is closed.

Comment: I don't think Apple gonna approve your app if you try to update user's location every minute. That probably would consume a lot of the user's phone battery. 

About the push notification, that would be a remote push, so, you could every in your server if you had already sent a push in a certain time, for that specific store.

Comment: What you want to do can be done, but see [this answer][1] before you proceed.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847229/users-location-and-batterys-consumption

Comment: so this is possible even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that you take a look at Parse.com - A very mobile-friendly (both android, win and iOS) DB and library system. Easy to set up to user location and geolocation for your stores. Parse has an in-built push notification system, that works really easy, which could be triggered by how far you are from a store. Parse's DB is scalable and free to use until you reach a high level of user traffic in your app.

Take a look: [**Parse.com**](http://Parse.com)

Comment: Cool! You can easily start by doing these tutorials :) https://parse.com/apps/quickstart

Comment: does parse has QQ login? i see it has only fb, twitter and g+

Comment: @Ankit - Parse is not only made for FB and Twitter, you can make your own login also and might make a connection to QQ. Check connect.qq.com.